# Subquery returning more than 1 value - possible solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, subquery, date-arithmetic

I am converting all the EPOCH/UNIX timestamp to a date time format which works in a normal `SELECT` statement when executed, however, in a subquery it's throwing an error because it is returning the converted date for each `_id`.

This seems like a straight forward solution but for some reason I can't get my head round it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
  SELECT 
        [id] = A._id
        ,[conId] = A.conId
        ,[createdAt] = ISNULL(CAST(CASE  
                        WHEN ([createdAt]) = '\N' THEN @defaultDate
                        WHEN ([createdAt]) = '' THEN @defaultDate
                        WHEN ([createdAt]) IS NULL THEN @defaultDate
                        ELSE (SELECT [createdAt] = DATEADD(MS, CAST(createdAt AS BIGINT)%(3600*24*1000), 
                       DATEADD(DAY, CAST(createdAt AS BIGINT)/(3600*24*1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0')) FROM areas)
                    END AS DATETIME2(7)), @defaultDate)
        FROM areas A
```

Comment: The error is telling your the problem here; your subquery is returning more that one result when it isn't allow to. I suspect that your subquery requires an lateral join in the `WHERE` though what that join is is a different question that only you will know.

Comment: Why parentheses around a scalar value? Why use regular identifier delimiters that are not needed? Storing epoch time values (and why do that in the first place) - just materialize that as a date as a computed column in the table so you NEVER need to write this expression again. And why is it stored as a string? Make your life and code simpler, easier to read / understand, less prone to error.

Comment: its stored as a string because the datasource i'm getting the data from is a MongoDB JSON file which displays the EPOCH date as a string. So in this scenario I couldn't "make my code simpler"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would need a subquery at all, when it seems like you just want to convert the epoch timestamp on the current row.

As for error handling, I would recommend `try_convert` rather than a `case` expression. Finally, you can assign the default value with `coalesce()`.

```
select id, conid,
    coalesce(
        dateadd(second, try_convert(bigint, createdat), '19700101'), 
        @defaultdate
    ) as createdat
from areas
```

Comment: ahh it now clicked! I never even needed the subquery